# Switching between HID devices on Windows (software or hardware)

Tags: windows, usb, keyboard, mouse, hid

I need to control a single PC (Windows) from two locations, i.e. two monitors, two keyboards, two mice, but while the monitors may show the same screen, only one location may use keyboard and mouse. The HID are connected via USB. As far as I know, HID are always used in parallel by default, which is not desired.
The aim is to have the computer control which devices are active.

Options:

- unplug or switch physically:

  - unplugging manually is not an option
  - switching may cause problems due to electrical or timing issues

    - solid state solution required (maybe use KVM in reverse?)
    - special hardware/electronics neccessary for solution that should be possible to be implemented in software
- software solution:

  - is there a way to manipulate Windows' HID handling (select which physical device controls HID)?
  - find a way to unplug/enable/eject/disable HID USB devices in software
  - implement muxing driver that intercepts USB HID and emulates virtual HID

A solution would also be interesting with regard to using a cheap mouse as a sensor device (or switch input), i.e. preventing it from influencing the cursor but instead reading it directly with own software.
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Windows already supports this.  Partially because of the HID specs and partially because of the American Disability Act.

Where you might run into trouble though is if your mouse requires special software for it's extra functions.  But without the special software, your mouse will at the very least support x,y movement and two buttons.  Mouse wheel support, IIRC, is not 100% supported.